# ecommerce: an intelligent shopping cart.

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter, e-commerce

Say a user came onto my website and bought a shed. The shed would be added to the cart and job done.
In my database I have the shed's dimensions already (to display to the customer).

Say the customer also wanted a carpet for the shed (you never know) I want my web application to automatically understand that the carpet will be for the shed and will only allow a user to select a maximum square meter from a drop down box based on the dimensions of the shed. I'll give an example:

Shed = 1.83m x 2.44m x 1.55 = (width x depth x height)
To calculate the square meters I'd multiply width and depth == 4.46 -> 5 would be my maximum square meter variable.
How do I update the CARPET product based on what's in the shopping cart... like my shed.

Thanks for your time, and apologies for no code, I hope you understand what I mean I'm running in circles atm.

Comment: What if I just want a shed for my backyard and a carpet for my living room? Also instead of "minimum", don't you mean maximum (ie, the carpet would fit inside the shed)?

Comment: What happens if someone adds more than one shed to their shopping cart before then shopping for carpet?

Comment: im using this as an example, in my application, the carpet will always be needed for the shed and only one shed will be needed.

Comment: Uhm, as a customer I wouldn't like the idea...as a developer, neither

Comment: +1, it's actually quite a good question, perhaps worded a little confusingly. I interpret this as a kind of a "related" products setup, with sufficient logic to handle the above + other scenarios.

Comment: i've not been entirely honest, the shopping cart is in fact a quote not being bought online, the user may only require a shed but i am offering the carpet as well. Being able to automatically understand the sizes means the customer doesn't have to think, just click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your visitor cart was stored in the $_SESSION, you could have the item page (a) check to see if CARPETs are being browsed, and if so (b) parse the $_SESSION to see if the visitor cart contains a SHED. If so, it could then calculate the carpet area based on the visitor's chosen shed dimensions (also stored in the $_SESSION).

Comment: understood, what happens (mentioned in the comments above) if the user does decide to add another shed, could the session be updated to a new shed if the carpet has already been chosen for the first shed.

Comment: sure ... $_SESSION['cart'][1] = array('name'=>'Lovely Shed','size'=>'12x24','carpeted'=>0); ... carpeted defaults to 0, and then the above carpet order would change 'carpeted' to 1. additional carpet orders would not show uncarpeted sheds in the $_SESSION, until a new shed was added (where 'carpeted'=>0)